# Código php fica comentado no html

Tags: php, html

Estou criando um captcha em um formulário de cadastro, e estou chamando a imagem com um comando php, mas a imagem do captcha não aparece no formulário, e quando entro no console do navegador o código php está comentado.

Código no editor está assim:

```
<?php require_once('imagem_seguranca.php'); ?>
```

E no console aparece comentado assim:

```
<!--<?php require_once('imagem_seguranca.php'); ?>-->
```

Código do arquivo 'imagem-seguranca.php'

```
<?php $imagem = mt_rand(0,4);?>
<img src="captcha.php?iu=<?php echo $imagem; ?>" />
```

Comment: Local ou no servidor remoto?

Comment: Podes juntar mais código? somente esse pedaço nõ dá ideia sobre qual pode ser o problema...

Comment: Qual o nome do arquivo que tem essa parte? -> `<?php require_once('imagem_seguranca.php'); ?>`

Comment: form_captcha.php

Comment: Tenha certeza que a extensão está como `.php` e não `.html`. Se estiver certo, edite a questão e coloque mais detalhes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um arquivo que puxa outro arquivo que puxa a imagem...

Faça uma vez só.

Onde você quer colocar o captcha, faça:

`<img src="captcha.php?iu=<?php echo mt_rand(0,4); ?>" />`